# I am getting error Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0009' Subscript out of range: 'j'

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to insert data in classic asp but getting following error:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0009'  Subscript out of range: 'j'

For reference I am attaching my code. I am new to classic asp

```
IF Len(FixString(Request.Form("txtModelTypeID"))) >= 1 AND cboSlab = "SlabCombineSeries" Then

                arrModelTypeID = split(trim(Request.Form("txtModelTypeID")),",")
                arrModelID = split(trim(Request.Form("txtModelID")),",")
                arrSlab = split(trim(Request.Form("txtSlab")),",")
                arrAmount = split(trim(Request.Form("txtAmount")),",")
                arrSF = split(trim(Request.Form("txtSF")),",")
                arrNonSF = split(trim(Request.Form("txtNonSF")),",")
                arrPMY = split(trim(Request.Form("txtPMY")),",")
                arrCMY = split(trim(Request.Form("txtCMY")),",")
                arrPIY = split(trim(Request.Form("txtPIY")),",")
                arrCIY = split(trim(Request.Form("txtCIY")),",")
                arrTradeIn = split(trim(Request.Form("txtTradeIn")),",")
                arrLoyalty = split(trim(Request.Form("txtLoyalty")),",")
                arrSpecial1 = split(trim(Request.Form("txtSpecial1")),",")
                arrSpecial2 = split(trim(Request.Form("txtSpecial2")),",")
                arrSpecial3 = split(trim(Request.Form("txtSpecial3")),",")

    arrkeydiscount = split(trim(Request.Form("txtkeydiscount")),",")
    arrsme = split(trim(Request.Form("txtsme")),",")
                if ubound(arrModelTypeID) = 0 Then

                elseif ubound(arrModelTypeID) > 0 Then
                    FOR j = 0 to ubound(arrModelTypeID)

                        if NOT ISNumeric(TRIM(arrSlab(j))) Then Slab = 0 else Slab = TRIM(arrSlab(j)) end if
                        if NOT ISNumeric(TRIM(arrAmount(j))) Then Amount = 0 else Amount = TRIM(arrAmount(j))  end if
                        if NOT ISNumeric(TRIM(arrSF(j))) Then SF = 0 else SF = TRIM(arrSF(j))  end if
                        if NOT ISNumeric(TRIM(arrNonSF(j))) Then NonSF = 0 else NonSF = TRIM(arrNonSF(j))  end if
                        if NOT ISNumeric(TRIM(arrPMY(j))) Then PMY = 0 else PMY = TRIM(arrPMY(j))  end if
                        if NOT ISNumeric(TRIM(arrCMY(j))) Then CMY = 0 else CMY = TRIM(arrCMY(j))  end if
                        if NOT ISNumeric(TRIM(arrPIY(j))) Then PIY = 0 else PIY = TRIM(arrPIY(j))  end if
                        if NOT ISNumeric(TRIM(arrCIY(j))) Then CIY = 0 else CIY = TRIM(arrCIY(j))  end if
                        if NOT ISNumeric(TRIM(arrTradeIn(j))) Then TradeIn = 0 else TradeIn = TRIM(arrTradeIn(j))  end if
                        if NOT ISNumeric(TRIM(arrLoyalty(j))) Then Loyalty = 0 else Loyalty = TRIM(arrLoyalty(j))  end if
                        if NOT ISNumeric(TRIM(arrSpecial1(j))) Then Special1 = 0 else Special1 = TRIM(arrSpecial1(j))  end if
                        if NOT ISNumeric(TRIM(arrSpecial2(j))) Then Special2 = 0 else Special2 = TRIM(arrSpecial2(j))  end if
                        if NOT ISNumeric(TRIM(arrSpecial3(j))) Then Special3 = 0 else Special3 = TRIM(arrSpecial3(j))  end if
if NOT ISNumeric(TRIM(arrkeydiscount (j))) Then Key = 0 else Key = TRIM(arrkeydiscount(j))  end if
    if NOT ISNumeric(TRIM(arrsme (j))) Then Sme = 0 else Sme = TRIM(arrsme(j))  end if

                        SQL = SQL & "INSERT INTO demo_Item ( " &_
                                " iSPCMasterID, iModelID, vModelName, vModelCode, iSlab, mAmount, " &_
                                " mSF, mNonSF, mPMY, mCMY, mPIY, mCIY, mTradeIn, mLoyalty, " &_
                                " mSpecial1, mSpecial2,key_acc,sme, mSpecial3, dCreateDate, iSeq) " &_
                                " SELECT @NewID, i_modelid, vch_modelname, modelcode, " &_
                                " " & Slab & ", " &_
                                " " & Amount & ", " &_
                                " " & SF & ", " &_
                                " " & NonSF & ", " &_
                                " " & PMY & ", " &_
                                " " & CMY & ", " &_
                                " " & PIY & ", " &_
                                " " & CIY & ", " &_
                                " " & TradeIn & ", " &_
                                " " & Loyalty & ", " &_
                                " " & Special1 & ", " &_
                                " " & Special2 & ", " &_
    " " & Key & ", " &_
    " " & Sme & ", " &_
                                " " & Special3 & " , getdate(), " & j + 1 &_
                                " FROM ltr_or_models WHERE CAST(i_modeltypeid as varchar(20)) = '" & trim(arrModelTypeID(j)) &  "' " 
                    next
                end if
```

Comment: Hi - did you know that you can get ASP to tell you the exact line and character of the error? It is a lot better than hunting for a bug in a dense code block like the one you posted. Google for ` server.getlasterror`, and see sites like http://www.dylanbeattie.net/2008/12/fun-with-servergetlasterror-in-classic.html for advice, particularly about mapping 500 errors to a customer error handler. If you need to debug ASP this is invaluable.

Comment: The formatting on this post is terrible - please edit your post and format your code.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to loop through multiple arrays simultaneously using a single counter. I.E. You are setting the end of the j counter using the upper level of the arrModelTypeID array and then expecting the remaining and separate arrays (arrSlab, arrAmount etc.) to use the same counter.

Assuming the data in all your newly created arrays are ordered identically to each other. Try checking each array record for a value before setting its assigned variable.

E.G. CHANGE

```
if NOT ISNumeric(TRIM(arrSlab(j))) Then Slab = 0 else Slab = TRIM(arrSlab(j)) end if
```

TO

```
If arrSlab(j) <> "" Then
if NOT ISNumeric(TRIM(arrSlab(j))) Then Slab = 0 else Slab = TRIM(arrSlab(j)) end if
End If
```